# Ruby Mechanize Page to String

Tags: ruby, string, mechanize-ruby

I have captured a Mechanize page.  How can I get that item into a string?  Pretty Print is used to output that object, however I'd like to get that into a string for further instructions.  I can't seem to find any method.

Any advice appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: @sawa Like I said, it's a Mechanize Page.  That is an object.  I can Pretty Print that object, and it outputs.  Its object.class is a Mechanize::Page.  I'd like to get that output into a string so I can use it elsewhere.  But the class has no way of coercing that output into a string.  An how his comment is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Never needed to save the page content to a string but this works:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.com")
s = page.content
```